# Daily recurring notifications in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to use the plugin, [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)   to send recurring notifications to the user, every day but the resource available for the plugin consists of only code and is incomprehensible, I have done the setup for the plugin as follows:

- added the dependency of [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)
- added the permission code for iOS in the `AppDelegate.swift`

I did this much by referring to numerous resources like [medium](https://medium.com) and a few other sites, so can someone please write a method which sends the user (android & iOS) a recurring notification everyday? Thank you!

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I am sorry I did not, I found a resource for scheduled notifications but not recurring ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing that comment I did a bit of research and this is working for me so far:

```
Future<void> showAlertNotification() async {
    var time = Time(8, 0, 0);
    var androidChannel = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channelID', 'channelName', 'channelDescription',
        importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
        priority: Priority.defaultPriority,
        playSound: true);

    var iosChannel = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannel =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidChannel, iOS: iosChannel);
   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(2, 'notification title',
            'message here', time, platformChannel,
            payload: 'new payload'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use showDailyAtTime as of now it has quite a number of problems like syncing up with local time zones. So instead you should use the zoned schedule but you should first initialize it with your local time zone it can be done with another package called flutter_native_timezone. This is the workflow I used:

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
Future<void> showNotif() async {
tz.initializeTimeZones();
String dtz = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
if (dtz == "Asia/Calcutta") {
  dtz = "Asia/Kolkata";
}
final localTimeZone = tz.getLocation(dtz);
tz.setLocalLocation(localTimeZone);
await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(..., matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time);
}
```

// The ... above is the usual parameters that I didn't write.

Comment: This example missing most of parameters.

Comment: But will this repeat daily? I don't think so

Comment: @Usama, yes it would repeat. Just read the documentation of the zonedSchedule function in the definition file